# GWT simple form validation example

Tags: validation, gwt

I'm looking for nice and fast way for validating forms in GWT, that can display errors one by one, focusing on the offending field. I've found gwt-validator and gwt-validation, but their documentation lack of examples.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try the Hupa source code, If I remember well they use a GWT validation framework. Hupa is an open source project from Apache.